# jquery auto refresh script problem

Tags: php, jquery, events

i wrote myself a block of jquery codes to auto refresh a div

just want it to reload every 10 seconds . but problem is after the time i specified in my code script going crazy reload every second

```
    <script>
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function(){
    $(\'#showDIV\').slideUp(\'300\').load(\'movies.php\').slideDown(500);},10000);
    </script>
```

Comment: Mac - can you clarify what is wrong... do you want it to reload every 1, 5, or 10 seconds?

Comment: it simple just want it to reload every 10 seconds . but problem is after the time i specified in my code , script going crazy reload every second

Comment: ah, ok got it. and the initial 5 seconds... do you have another timer that delays the start of the refresh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to use `setTimeout()` and not `setInterval()`

read the difference between the two [here](http://javascript.about.com/library/blstvsi.htm).